# WPF Binding & MemberwiseClone Problems

Tags: wpf, binding, clone, observablecollection

I'm working on a WPF project and have implemented a very simple way to undo one level of change which works nicely throughout the project except for one case where changes to an object's property reflects in the MemberwiseClone.

What I am doing is to do a MemberwiseClone in my object before adding or editing properties in that object, and then if the user wants to undo, I copy each property from the MemberwiseClone object back into my current object.

Because I am using WPF binding, using the MemberwiseClone is attractive to me because up until now, any change made in a property was not reflected in the MemberwiseClone.  This time I have a property in my object that is an ObservableCollection of another object, and what is happening is that if I add an item to the ObservableCollection, it also gets added to the object created by MemberwiseClone and I can never truly undo.

Is there any way around this? Any thoughts you might have on this are welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Object.MemberwiseClone Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) the object references in your `ObservableCollection` will be copied but not the referenced object itself. Therefore your undo collection references the same possible changed objects.

You need a deep copy, not a shallow one. Take a look at [How do you do a deep copy an object in .Net (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/129389/620360)

Comment: I am working with the extension method in the link, however I get the following exception: Type 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager' in Assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

Any thoughts?  I have marked all of my classes as Serializable.

Comment: You have to use [Serializable] attribute on your class with ObservableCollection. See [Basic Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: LPL, Yes, I had marked all of my classes as Serializable, but needed the NonSerializedAttribute to make this work.  Thank you very much for the link and your very helpful answer.